# While doing TDD, when to implement a new mocked dependency?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, language-agnostic, mocking, tdd

There's one question I can't find an answer to, concerning TDD with the outside-in approach:

I implement a new unit (A), write a test for it and this unit needs a dependency (B) that does not exist yet. In my test it's easy to mock this dependency, but what do I do in my production code?

Do I implement (B) first and let my tests for (A) fail meanwhile because I haven't gone on implementing it to make its tests pass yet?

Or do I complete (A) first and meanwhile let tests for (B) fail because it e.g. just returns "empty" objects instead of actually doing what its specification tells it to do?

Or should I let (B)'s tests temporarily check that it returns "empty" objects while I keep implementing (A) - although that's actually not what (B)'s specification is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fundamental strategy of TDD is to keep all your tests passing except for the one you're working on right now. Make (A)'s tests pass before you worry about (B).

The order in which you'd write tests and code for a class (A) and its complicated dependency (B) is

- Write a test for (A). [Suite is red.]
- Begin implementing enough of (A) to get the test you just wrote to pass. Discover that you need (B). [Suite is red.]
- Mock (B). [Suite is red.]
- Finish making the test of (A) that you just wrote pass. [Suite is green. Ahhh!] Refactor.
- If you're not at a good stopping point with (A) yet, go back to the top and repeat until you are at a good stopping point with (A).
- Write a test for (B) that requires (B) to do part or all of what the mock of (B) does. [Suite is red.]
- Make the test you just wrote pass. [Suite is green. Ahhh!] Refactor.
- If you haven't replicated all of what the mock of (B) does in tests and code of (B) yet, go back two steps and repeat until you've replicated all of what the mock of (B) does.

At this point you can choose to work some more on (A) or (B) or start something new.

Although this strategy keeps your tests passing at all times, it does not ensure that your application does something useful right away. The way to ensure that your application eventually does something useful goes beyond TDD: start by writing an acceptance test (which runs against the entire application without mocks) and TDD until the acceptance test and your unit tests all pass. (See [bdd](/questions/tagged/bdd) for more.)

Acceptance tests (or other integration tests) also ensure that you correctly replicate mocks in your tests of and code for mocked classes.

Note also that it's critical to keep track of requirements that you've thought of but not implemented yet, or that you've 'implemented' only in a mock and need to implement in tests of and code for the mocked dependency. That's why [TDD By Example](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321146530) and other examples of how TDD is done talk so much about actual or mental to-do lists. In the case of a class (A) with a mocked dependency (B), after you write the mock you can either go back to working on (A) or implement in (B) what you just did with the mock. Either way, you have to keep track of what you chose *not* to do until you're ready to go back and do it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to have a dependency on B only as soon as you really need B in your code. If nothing in A depends on B, why add it at this stage?

If your code really needs B now, why not starting implementing B's features that you need now?

Of course you can also use a dummy object in your code instead of B if it does not have any logic. Otherwise I would start implementing B.